# Does a projection's WKT reflect the computer's locale?

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text, internationalization

This should be quick - we're trying to determine if there are problems parsing some WKT text because the system locale considers the decimal separator to be a comma instead of a period.

Anyone know?  References would be handy so I can show the devs.

Our specific implementation is using Esri's Web ADF but I am curious to know how other systems handle it, and whether or not the OGC has established an official opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a developer, the projection engine library ignores locale when writing (and reading) WKT strings. The decimal is always a period.

Melita Kennedy
Esri product engineer

Comment: Melita, I presume that's "the *arcgis* projection library..."? (and it's convention here not to sign posts. People can click through to your user page to get more info)

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt go to the OGC Spec (http://portal.opengeospatial.org/modules/admin/license_agreement.php?suppressHeaders=0&access_license_id=3&target=http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/index.php?artifact_id=25355) which when you follow through all the BNF on page 53 indicates that a period or a comma are acceptable decimal points.

Answer (score 2):

This FAQ suggests that you might find problems with GDAL, but you should mention what software you are using:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQMiscellaneous#DoesGDALworkindifferentinternationalnumericlocales